# Working with active/inactive records in .net core

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

We are having number of lookup tables and there ids are referred in other tables. In lookup tables we have IsActive flag to decide whether that value should be shown in dropdown OR not.

So, my question is if that particular value(id specifically) is used in other tables and which is inactive now, then how can i show that particular value in the dropdown.

For e.g. 
States LookUp Table Model

```
public int StateId { get; set; }
public string StateName { get; set; }
public string StateAbbreviation { get; set; }
public bool IsActive { get; set; }
```

Employee Model

```
public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
public int StateId { get; set; }
public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
public string Designation { get; set; }
public bool IsActive { get; set; }
```

Now, if we have created employee which uses stateid, and after some days that stateid set to isactive = false. And if we are going to access employee record which has used that stateid and now it is inactive, then how can we show that value in dropdown?

As we are populating only active values in the dropdown.

We are populating the dropdown values on form load in separate api and the actual records(employee in this case) in separate api.

StateLookUpDto

```
public int StateId { get; set; }
public string StateName { get; set; }
public string StateAbbreviation { get; set; }
```

EmployeeDto

```
public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
public int StateId { get; set; }
public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
public string Designation { get; set; }
```

Any help on this appreciated !

Comment: @@XamDev i think u need to join  both the tables...and check your column value is active or not...

Comment: @AkhileshSingh Yeah, but we are returning the lookup values separately and the actual record(Employee in this case) separately

Comment: @@XamDev..i think.. your Query..should be like this... SELECT e.EmployeeId,e.EmployeeName  FROM 
dbo.tbl_EmployeeModel e
INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_LookUpTable t 
ON e.StateId=t.StateId
WHERE isnull(t.IsActive,0)=1 ....if active then it will pick the records..

Comment: @AkhileshSingh I have edited my question.. Can you please look ?